# socket io changes socket.id repeatedly

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Is this normal behavior?
     **socket.io-1.3.2.js**
From the client:

```
socket = io.connect('https://socket.myserver.nl');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('register', userID, 'Lobby');//ignore this
    });
```

At the server **Node version v5.2.0**:

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('SOCKET CONNECTING '+socket.id); 
  ////lots of other code//////////


  socket.on('disconnect', function() {  
    console.log('SOCKET DISCONNECTING '+socket.id);    
  });
  });
```

During test when i make a single connection with a client to the server and further doing absolutely nothing i get the following (5 minutes approximately):

SOCKET CONNECTING SddHIXmWSeHEfDnlAAAC

SOCKET DISCONNECTING SddHIXmWSeHEfDnlAAAC

SOCKET CONNECTING o0zj7GE1tlO3RQw1AAAD

SOCKET DISCONNECTING o0zj7GE1tlO3RQw1AAAD

SOCKET CONNECTING lAnfvaF3DXMyhc6lAAAE

SOCKET DISCONNECTING lAnfvaF3DXMyhc6lAAAE

SOCKET CONNECTING tP3cjtJ-VpPPjoG2AAAF

SOCKET DISCONNECTING tP3cjtJ-VpPPjoG2AAAF

SOCKET CONNECTING a2o13T7CgcKDEbppAAAG

SOCKET DISCONNECTING a2o13T7CgcKDEbppAAAG

SOCKET CONNECTING avogGTh0KVtLFOqNAAAH

SOCKET DISCONNECTING avogGTh0KVtLFOqNAAAH

SOCKET CONNECTING usoQGxKAMsth2zTcAAAI

SOCKET DISCONNECTING usoQGxKAMsth2zTcAAAI

question continues here: [socket-io-changes-socket-id-repeatedly part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334399/socket-io-changes-socket-id-repeatedly-part-2)

Comment: This happens only when you refresh the browser (Client) or there is network problem when internet connection is not persistent.

Comment: I'm in the netherlands with -i believe- very stable connection to the internet. Problem i have with this phenomenon is that when a client enters the site i want to store their userinfo together with the socket id. Sometimes on the server the id has to be found based on the username to send things. I believe it is socketio that does this automatically with no possibillity to send userinfo again while reconnecting?

Comment: There's [`reconnect` event](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

Comment: *"and further doing absolutely nothing* - that's very unlikely. Either you restarted the server, or you refreshed the page or your internet connection was disconnected and reconnected, something like that must be happening. Anyway to handle such scenarios you'll need to implement user sessions, probably based on cookies, search for session management using socket io

Comment: Try turning on socket.io debug logging: `env DEBUG=socket.io:* node app` (provided that you're using some sort of Unix-type OS).

Comment: @  T J  Ok then, i was looking at the terminal window and drinking coffee. ;-)  I'll look into session management with socket.io. The application i'm developing was first only php but it wouldn't surprise me if it's going to be completely node. It was this at the beginning https://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/  from which still php-sessions are used and etc.

Comment: @robertklep This one DEBUG=* node yourfile.js is indeed giving a very verbose output when issued to run the server. This can run during normal operations and written to a file or something?  And this one:  localStorage.debug = '*'; ? On the webpage simply enter it in the console and see what happens? Cause i do'nt see anything happening...

Comment: @ingridsede you could log the output to a file (append `> socket.io.log` to the command I mentioned). There would be _some_ performance impact, although I doubt it would be noticeable. And you're correct about the client-side debugging: just issue the command in console and keep it open to see log messages appearing.

Comment: @robertklep Awesome! Issuing this at the terminal indeed produces a log in the same dir: DEBUG=* node server.js append > socket.io.log . Funny thing with you Nerds that you'll never would answer a question like: Well, issue this command (ie DEBUG=* node server.js append > socket.io.log) and a log gets created in the same dir your server is in.. :-) Good to know about this logging feature! Thanks!

Comment: started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334399/socket-io-changes-socket-id-repeatedly-part-2

Comment: @robertklep I had this "localStorage.debug" entered in my console and notice that's there to stay? How do i stop this thing from logging? I even reinstalled chrome for other reasons but it's still flooding the console.....

Comment: @ingridsede try `localStorage.debug = null` to disable logging

Comment: Thought i already tried that with no luck. Now it seems to do it. Must say that i had other problems with my chrome and reinstalled it to see that this debugger was still bugging me. :-) Now it's gone. Thanks.

Comment: You might have made an error by calling a new connection instance of socket oo everytime before emitting

Answer (score 3):

If you use React, Vue or something like that

Create another js file inside src and type these lines for connecting myCustomSocket.Export socket.id and socket. Because you need to run socket.io out of dynamic rendered components.

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
export let socketID = '';
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socketID = socket.id
})
```

And inside React components you can import them.

```js
import { socketID, socket } from './myCustomSocket';
```

Comment: Where is a 'connect' message emitted to set the socket id?