# socket-io-changes-socket-id-repeatedly part 2

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Following on the question asked by me:
[socket io changes socket.id repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326837/socket-io-changes-socket-id-repeatedly)

```
Registering only happens when the client comes on the chatpage:
```

On the client:

```
       socketConnect: function() {     
       socket =  io.connect('https://socket.mydomain.nl');

       socket.on('connect', function() {
       socket.emit('register', userID, 'Lobby');
       });
       };
```

Server

```
    var UserSockIdStorage = {},
         Allsocketids = [];

      //Clients connect and register here. 

        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {             
        socket.on("register", function(userID, currentchannel, userinfostr) {
        console.log('USER WITH ID ' + userID + ' REGISTERS WITH THE SOCKETIDOF: ' + socket.id); 

        UserSockIdStorage[userID] = socket.id; //userid is associated with the socket ID.
        socket.room = currentchannel;
        socket.join(currentchannel);
      });
```

As you can see i store the username in an array with the socket ID as its value.
When a message is to be send the username is looked up to retrieve the socket ID to send the message to.

Now come the part that i don't understand:

Clients keep reconnecting (Not registering so the socket id is not saved in the array!!) from time to time and i can see that they get another socket ID.

My guess would then be, that when i look up by username (Array UserSockIdStorage) a socket ID to send a message to, and the owner of that ID made several reconnects thus acquiring a new socket ID over and over again,
that a message send to the lookedUp socket ID  wouldn't go anywhere since the client obtained several new socket ID's in the meanwhile.

But from what i'm observing the message is routed to the correct client so the first socket ID is still it's socket ID?!

Are those ID's cached or somewhat?

Comment: I don't think the socket id's seem to have a lot to do with what you're talking about in the way you are describing. The sockets id's are a reference to the connection established by the client.  Any time a message is sent, it goes to that collection of connections that are still considered active.

Comment: If a client reconnects (not connects), the socket.id should remain the same. That is why you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean but if that means that the ID on start remains the same during login than it should be okay.

Comment: The socket.id will stay the same as long as the node server recognizes it has a reconnect, and not a new connection.

Comment: it should be noted that there are cases where I think it will create a new ID when it reconnects - dependent on specific error conditions.  I was getting transport errors and it would disconnect then reconnect but it wouldn't receive the messages anymore.  It was a bug with something kind of unrelated to socketio though (overriding setTimeout/setInterval screwed up the ping/pong).